# Delete specific sheets from Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a duplicate button on the excel ribbon which when clicked, will create a duplicate file of the active workbook but I want it to create a duplicate file having only first two sheets copied in the duplicate file and not the whole active workbook.

I tried the below code for getting the duplicate file :

```
Sub DupliquerFeuille(control As IRibbonControl)
        Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With
        Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
        'Copy the sheet to a new workbook
        nom = Day(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Year(Date) & "_" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & nom
        ' ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array(1, 2)).Copy
   End Sub
```

But I am getting all sheets of active workbook copied in the duplicate file. Can anyone please help me in getting only the first  sheets of active workbook copied in the duplicate file. I tried a lot but I am unable to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub DupliquerFeuille(control As IRibbonControl)

Dim twb As Workbook
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Const shc As Long = 2 ' change this as you need, this will copy first 2 sheets

With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = False
   .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
Sourcewb.Sheets(1).Copy
Set twb = ActiveWorkbook

For i = 2 To shc
 Sourcewb.Sheets(i).Copy ,twb.Sheets(twb.Sheets.Count)
Next
nom = Day(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Year(Date) & "_" & Sourcewb.Name
twb.SaveAs Sourcewb.Path & "\" & nom, Sourcewb.FileFormat
twb.Close False

With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .EnableEvents = True
End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: This code works fine but in the duplicate file, i am getting sheet1 at the last.  Suppose i copy first 4 sheets, so in the duplicate file, i am getting Sheets in the order of 2 - 3 - 4 - 1

Comment: @RishavTripathi, this will copy sheets in the same order in the source file.

Comment: But in my case it is not copying sheets in the same order

Comment: so you need to copy the first 4 sheets in same order. i will test again

Comment: I want to copy the first 4 sheets in the same order of 1 - 2 - 3 - 4

Comment: oh yes just add `,` after copy

Answer (score 0):

Below code lines find the path and name of current excel file, copy the first two sheets and save to a new (duplicated) workbook in the same location as the main workbook:

```
 Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

' Create path and name for export
PathName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "_export"

' Copy the sheets so they don't get removed in the main file
Sheets(Array(1, 2)).Copy Before:=Sheets(1)

' Move the first two sheets to a new workbook
Sheets(Array(1, 2)).Move

' Save the active duplicated workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathName, FileFormat:=Sourcewb.FileFormat

' Close the active duplicated workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: It does work but doesn't solve my purpose. I want the duplicate button to copy the first two files in a new file and save it in a specific path without opening that duplicate file.  I was able to achieve the same result as i am getting by "move" when i used the code "ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array(1, 2)).Copy"

Comment: I'm a bit confused what the current issue is? The code I suggested moves only a subset of sheets to a new workbook, then with this as the active workbook you can use your existing code to save that workbook. I believe that this duplicated workbook needs to be open during this process. You can close this duplicated workbook after using a command like `ActiveWorkbook.Close` - does this help?

Comment: It is promting me to give the location/path for saving the duplicate file. Can i use a code for automatically saving the file to a specific path with a specific name ?
I used "ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & nom" but its showing error

Comment: yup, give me a few mins, I will adjust my previous solution

Answer (score 0):

How about just adding an extra few lines of code after you save the new workbook to delete out those pages you don't like?

Such as

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Replace "Sheet 1" with the name of the sheet (keep the quotation marks)

Comment: oh and I spose you would have to save again

Comment: There is no specific name of the first two sheets, I want to make it  dynamic